# SQL for searching for gaps

Tags: php, magento

I wrote a query that searches for gaps in sku numbers in Magento. It works perfect in PHPAdmin, but returns empty when I test it in a php page.

```
    $dbread = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$strSQL="SELECT * 
FROM catalog_product_entity
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS t2 ON CAST( t2.sku AS UNSIGNED ) = CAST( catalog_product_entity.sku AS UNSIGNED ) +1
WHERE t2.sku IS NULL 
AND CAST( catalog_product_entity.sku AS UNSIGNED ) >100000
LIMIT 1";
$sql = $dbread->query($strSQL);
$res = $sql->fetchAll();
var_dump($res);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Lots. What have you tried, though? That usually helps narrow down the issue. If the query itself works, it may be an issue with the php code. Are you getting any errors? Are you testing the query locally, which might have different versions MySql on your production server?

Comment: I get no error just an empty array. The MySQL version is 5.1.73. I am more of a .Net and java programmer. I just know enough php to get in trouble. Thank God for google and forums. I am testing on the live server.

Comment: Try some experiments to see if the problem is the SQL or the PHP.  What happens if you replace the SQL lookup entirely with `$res = "hello"`?

Comment: Maybe it's the connection string? Try some simple queries to see if you're actually connecting to your DB. You just might be getting warnings or notices that are getting hidden.

Comment: I can replace $strSQL with a simple query and get a response. I figure it is something in the query, but it was the only query I could get to work in PHPAdmin that gave the result I needed. The sku is saved as a string. Due to repeated human error the numbers jump around heavily. So I am trying to determin a way to get the next available sku number after 100,000. This query returns the last number and then I just have to add 1 to it. If someone nows a query that is better, please pass it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a test table and ran your code. When I did, I got an array with `NULL`s in it as the output. I adjusted the code to:

```
$dbread = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$strSQL="SELECT t1.sku 
FROM catalog_product_entity t1
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS t2 ON CAST( t2.sku AS UNSIGNED ) = CAST( t1.sku AS UNSIGNED ) +1
WHERE t2.sku IS NULL 
AND CAST( t1.sku AS UNSIGNED ) >100000
LIMIT 1";
$sql = $dbread->query($strSQL);
$res = $sql->fetchAll();
var_dump($res);
```

And was able to get the proper result. I don't know why exactly, but I assume something about the `SELECT *` mixed with `var_dump` was causing it to return just the fields from the `NULL` in `t2`. Since you only need the last `sku` from `t1`, no reason to return the rest of it.

But maybe this is not the issue you were having. If you could supply the output you get and the output you are expecting to get, that would help.